# How do I convert passed flags/arguments to my Perl program without parsing them myself?

Tags: perl, parsing, arguments

I would like to pass a perl program a set of arguments and flags, e.g. `my_script.pl --flag1 --arg1=value --flag2 …`

Is there a way to quickly convert all of these into some standard structure (hash) instead of parsing?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: A helpful tutorial on PerlMonks about using `Getopt::Long` and `Pod::Usage` to produce options+documentation easily: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=155288

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use [Getopt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html)

Sample:

```
linux-t77m:/home/vinko # more opt.pl
use Getopt::Long;    
my $arg1 = 'default_value';
GetOptions('flag1' => \$flag1, 'arg1=s' => \$arg1, 'flag2' => \$flag2);    
print "FLAG1: ".$flag1." ARG1: ".$arg1." FLAG2: ".$flag2."\n\n";

linux-t77m:/home/vinko # perl opt.pl --flag2 --arg1=stack
FLAG1:  ARG1: stack FLAG2: 1

linux-t77m:/home/vinko # perl opt.pl --flag1 --flag2
FLAG1: 1 ARG1: default_value  FLAG2: 1
```

Comment: Also check out [MooseX::Getopt](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MooseX::Getopt), which uses Getopt::Long to convert arguments to Moose attributes. :)

Answer (score 1):

`GetOptions` also can fill a hash as requested in the question.

```
my %opt;
GetOptions(\%opt, qw(flag1 arg1=s flag2)) or pod2usage(2);
```